# Serilog logging in background task

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, hangfire

I have an ASP.NET 6 API project and having an issue with logging from methods that are run by a hangfire background job.

I setup Serilog just like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYKTwvowMUI)

It works great in the controller or any other class/method that is called from the controller (i.e. same thread as the incoming request). Simply using Dependency Injection from the constructor and the logger object is initialized just fine.

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyController> _logger;

    public MyController(ILogger<MyController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> MyActionMethod([FromBody] RequestBody request)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("This works fine");

        var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue<JobHandler>(x =>
                handler.Main(param1, param2, param3);

        return Ok($"Job dispatched successfully, id: {jobId}");
    }
```

The problem lies when trying to log from within the code that is being run by the background job.
Using DI doesn't resolve the logger object and always returns null.

I have a `LogService` that I use in various parts of the project, and `logger` always resolves to null.

```
public class LogService
{
    private readonly ILogger<LogService> _logger;

    public LogService(ILogger<LogService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void LogSolverStatus(RoutingModel model)
    {
        string status = model.GetStatus().ToString();
        //Console.WriteLine($"Done Solving, Solution Status: {status}");

        // This doesn't work because _logger is null and throws an exception
        _logger.LogInformation("Done Solving, Solution Status: {status}", status);
    }
```

One solution is [passing dependencies](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/passing-dependencies.html) when firing the background job.

Is there a better/easier solution?

I understand from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61301952/impossible-to-use-dependency-injection-in-an-hangfire-job) that the logger is supposed to be registered as `Transient` or `Singleton`.

How can I do this?

Comment: "The problem lies when trying to log from within the code that is being run by the background job. " You mind adding that code as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hi @Taher Elhouderi, I try to configure serilog in background job and it works fine. I wander how do you inject your `LogService`  into container and how to use `LogService`. Can you share the code about this if it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Serilog inside background worker, then first you need to initialize it as Singleton. I prefer creating static method and call it like that: `services.AddLogging()`

```
    private static IServiceCollection AddLogging(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        _loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Critical)
                .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Critical)
                .AddFilter("ReturnCenter.API", LogLevel.Critical);
        }).AddFile("PATH");
        return services.AddSingleton(_loggerFactory);
    }
```

Then inside your class which inherits `BackgroundService` class, you should be able to get `ILogger` from DI like that inside your `ExecuteAsync` method:

```
using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    var logger = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger>();
}
```